# Why does the if statements in my program not function when it's put in a function that's meant to run?

Tags: python

I have created a rock, paper scissors game in Python, posted it on replit, and now the 'if statements' refuse to function.

```
print("Welcome to the official game of Rock, Paper, Scissors!")
    
option = input('''Pick an option: Rock, Paper, Scissors
    >>> ''').lower()
    
import random
    
game_op =["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    computer_option = print(random.choice(game_op))
    
def options():
if option == "rock" and computer_option == "rock":
        print("You and the Computer chose the same options.")
        print('The end')
    
      elif option == "rock" and computer_option == "paper":
          print("The Computer wins!")
          print('The end')
          
      elif option == "rock" and computer_option == "scissors":
        print("You win!")
        print('The end')
    
      elif option == "paper" and computer_option == "rock":
        print("You win!")
        print('The end')
    
      elif option == "paper" and computer_option == "paper":
        print("You and the Computer chose the same options.")
        print('The end')
    
      elif option == "paper" and computer_option == "scissors":
        print("The Computer wins!")
        print('The end')
    
      elif option == "scissors" and computer_option == "rock":
        print("The Computer wins!")
        print('The end')
    
      elif option == "scissors" and computer_option == "scissors":
        print("You and the Computer chose the same options.")
        print('The end')
    
      elif option == "scissors" and computer_option == "paper":
        print("You win!")
        print('The end')`enter code here`
    
    
    print(options())
```

I tried making a function to handle the if statements and when you and the computer have decided on your move, the function works, but all its printing is 'None'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with the code that causes the issue in the text of your question, not as an external link

Comment: You never put a value into `computer_option` - you should say `computer_option = random.choice(game_op)` and then (if you want to) `print(computer_option)` as another action

Comment: Many other issues as well as the `computer_option` assignment. Like you define a function with `def options()` but you never use that function?

Comment: I tried your change in the computer_option error Joffan. My program is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have the line `option.lower`. This does not call any function nor does it reassign `option` to anything. Thus, if the user inputs `"ROCK"`, all the `if` and `elif` clauses will be ignored. Rewrite the first few lines to:

```py
print("Welcome to the official game of Rock, Paper, Scissors!")

option = input('''Pick an option: Rock, Paper, Scissors
>>> ''').lower()
```

Note that inputting something like `"banana"` will still cause all of the `if` and `elif` clauses to be ignored.

Comment: I tried to assign all if statements to a function. That way if the user inputs an answer, it turns to a lowercase word and the function is now called. Do you think that'll work because I'm currently trying to work on that?

Comment: The `.lower()` string method already does that. Other than that, I'm not quite sure what you mean.